# Unexpected mapping of exception from trigger - spring-boot 2.4.x + jOOQ

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

We are using spring-boot with spring-boot-starter-jooq. For some complex checks of constraints triggers are used which raise error with specific message. The exception is caught on persistence layer and converted into business exception.

The behavior has been changed in last spring boot versions 2.4.x. For example hsqldb with scherma:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
    K INT PRIMARY KEY
)^;

CREATE TRIGGER trig1 BEFORE INSERT ON tab1
BEGIN ATOMIC
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'some error';
END^;
```

and the code for insert into table:

```
    @Transactional
    public void withTriggerException() {
        create.insertInto(DSL.table("tab1"))
                .set(DSL.field("k"), 1)
                .execute();
    }
```

The type and the message of thrown exception differs from spring-boot version.

### 2.3.6, 2.3.9

`org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException`: jOOQ; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into tab1 (k) values (cast(? as int))]; SQL state [45000]; error code [5800]; some error; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: some error

### 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2

`java.lang.NullPointerException`: null

### 2.4.3

`org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException`: SQL [insert into tab1 (k) values (?)]; Unspecified RuntimeException

```
    at org.jooq_3.14.7.HSQLDB.debug(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2892) ~[jooq-3.14.7.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.exception(DefaultExecuteContext.java:730) ~[jooq-3.14.7.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqExceptionTranslator.handle(JooqExceptionTranslator.java:83) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqExceptionTranslator.exception(JooqExceptionTranslator.java:55) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.jooq.impl.ExecuteListeners.exception(ExecuteListeners.java:274) ~[jooq-3.14.7.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:390) ~[jooq-3.14.7.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDelegatingQuery.execute(AbstractDelegatingQuery.java:119) ~[jooq-3.14.7.jar:na]
    at com.example.demo.FooDAO.withTriggerException(DemoApplication.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
...
```

The behavior has been reproduced on hsqldb but is same on PostgreSQL. Another errors (duplicate key, foreign keys, etc.) are working as expected.

It is possible to obtain error message ("some error" in example) from trigger with spring-boot 2.4.x?

Comment: Looks like this has been caused by this change here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24064. Perhaps you can ask the authors of the change how to obtain the cause in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably ran into this issue:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11304, which has been fixed in jOOQ 3.14.6 and 3.15.0.

Some background on the incompatible change in Spring that produced this NPE regression in jOOQ can be seen here:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24064

The fix should be available in Spring Boot 2.5.0 and 2.4.3:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25214
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25240

You should be able to access the JDBC `SQLException` from jOOQ's `DataAccessException` using [`DataAccessException.getCause(Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/exception/DataAccessException.html#getCause(java.lang.Class)), e.g.

```java
exception.getCause(SQLException.class);
```

But there's probably a better way to have the Spring exception translator provide you with the actual cause directly.

Comment: Thank you for hint at jOOQ `DataAccessException.getCause(Class)`. But the method returns `null` in this case and does not solve the problem. I have added stack trace into original question (only for versions spring-boot 2.4.3 and jOOQ 3.14.7).

Comment: @user6606920: I can't say what's wrong from the description. I could take a look if you can a create a new issue https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose with steps to reproduce, ideally an MCVE: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve. But from a high level, this looks more like a Spring problem or Spring/jOOQ configuration problem than a mere jOOQ problem.

Comment: I agree that there is nothing wrong in jOOQ and the the bug is specific to spring-boot. I have created [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/25493) in spring-boot project.

Comment: I accepted the answer. Spring-boot in 2.4.4 has been fixed and `exception.getCause(SQLException.class)` now returns the original `SQLException`.